# How can I creat a bar in a cell of a Grid (ExtJS 3.3.1)

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have a grid that has an associated JsonStore and everything is populating great. I want to create in a column something like this:

[image: Sample Bars]

I am very new to Ext, but this is what I have so far in my ColumnModel:

```
     {
        header: 'Sales Rep', 
        width: 150, 
        sortable: true, 
        dataIndex: 'salesrep'
     },
     {
        header: 'graph',
        width: 150,          
        sortable: true, 
        dataIndex: 'ytd',
        renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store){
            var colChart = new Ext.chart.ColumnChart({
                store: store,
                xField: 'ytd',
                yField: 'salesrep'           
            });             
        }            
     },
     {
        header: 'Year to Date', 
        width: 150, 
        sortable: true, 
        dataIndex: 'ytd'
     },
```

The first and third column work as expected, but I am not seeing anything in the second. Anyone done anything like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using column renderer you are able to affect rendering via `metadata` object.

Unfortunately, it allows changing html attributes and css classes only.
Therefore either you need to try using css styles for chart generation or search for other ways possible, like creating ad hoc columns.

Comment: Ok, I see that now in the definition of the setRenderer method. So, basically I will need to use HTML and CSS to create a bar look. I can do that. I liked the snappy animation of the bar graph, though :)

Thanks.